# How to read table in R

Tags: r, igraph

I have the following table as txt

```
 community    its members
    1          12 15 4 6
    2          1 3 2 
    3          9 13 7 8 9
    4          5 10 11 14
```

This information is saved in community.txt, I was trying to import it in R as :

```
    library(igraph)
    community_table <- read.table("~/Desktop/community.txt", header= FALSE, sep = "" )
```

and got the error:

```
    Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
    line 1 did not have 6 elements
```

how I can import this in R !

thanks so much for any suggestion and help

Comment: Those are two very different questions. Breaking them up into two SO questions might be better (post the second one after you get the answer to the first one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import in R, try:

```
community_table <- read.table("~/Desktop/community.txt", header= FALSE, sep = "",fill = TRUE )
```

If you are able to import, please ask a separate question with an example dataset, the code you tried, and the expected output for the second part of your question.

Comment: Yes guys, this question has two parts, one is reading data and second is plotting community membership. They are relevant so can't be separate, as example @ujjwal suggest importing data in R and get result as:

Comment: 1 12 15 4 6 NA
      
 as first row , so the (NA) can affect the function of plotting I guess !

Comment: I have edited the question to focus in one part which is reading table into R 

Thanks @ujjwal